# Packaging Unreal Build Configurations

Tags: packaging, unreal-engine4, steamworks-api

I have integrated the Steam API with my project and I had to add the actual API to the include directories of my DebugGame_Editor Configuration as well as the library directory.

The editor has been building properly for a month and Steam runs in-game, but now I have gotten to packaging my game and I am getting an error:

> Cannot open include file: 'steam/steam_api.h': No such file or directory.

I assume that the configuration that it is using to package the game is missing those include directories and the library directory. Which configuration does UE4 use when packaging a game for Win64? There are like 40, and I don't want to try each and every one.

Engine Version: 4.7.6 from source (GitHub)

---

Edit:

I have gone through all configurations in the configuration manager in Visual Studio and added the two directories to the include and library sections of both Win32 and x64 in all of them (except the ones that say Mac or IOS), but no dice. It still throws that error message when it is trying to build `ProjectName.generated.cpp`

I'm not sure what to try next.

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to fix this problem by including the files with an absolute path, rather than relying on relative include paths.